# IE specific markup

Tags: html, internet-explorer-8

I am writing some markup, which includes a image below a `div`. I want to add another image when the browser is IE8. How do I write IE8 specific markup using javascript or JQuery?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need JS / Jquery for this, you can just use normal CSS.

All you're doing is adding a class to your HTML depending on the version of IE that is detected.

In your header add these (or a variation of) conditionals:

```
<!--[if lt IE 7]><html class="ie6"><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]><html class="ie7"><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]><html class="ie8"><![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--><html><!--<![endif]-->
```

Then you can show / hide elements in your CSS like so:

```
.ie8 .myImage {
   display: block;
}
.ie7 .myImage  {
   display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery to recognize Internet Explorer version 8.
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/

```
if ($.browser.msie && parseInt($.browser.version) == 8)
{
    //IE8 specific code block

}
```